# How to write on different output files at each iteration of loop? (Perl)

Tags: perl, file-io

I have a hash of hashes of hashes in Perl called `data` with first level keys: F, NF and S (basically, `%data={'F' => ..., 'NF' => ..., 'S' => ...}`)

At the beginning of my code I open 3 output handles:

```
open (my $fh1, ">>", $filename1) or die "cannot open > $filename1: $!";
open (my $fh2, ">>", $filename2) or die "cannot open > $filename2: $!";
open (my $fh3, ">>", $filename3) or die "cannot open > $filename3: $!";
```

Then, while my code runs, it populates the hash of hashes of hashes and, at the very end, I want to print the resulting hash of hashes for each key 'F', 'NF' and 'S' into a separate file (identified by the three file handles that I have defined in the beginning.) I'm not really sure how to do this. I have tried the following: right before the `foreach` loop in which I print the hash, I have defined

```
my @file_handles=($fh1, $fh2, $fh3);
my $handle_index=0;
```

and in each iteration of the hash I write to file by using

```
print $file_handles[$handle_index] "$stuff\n";
```

However, when I try to run the code, it tells me `string found where operator expected`
It's my understanding that I'm not telling him correctly which file handle he should use. Any suggestions?

Comment: In your hash assignment, you have a semi-colon `;` where you should have a comma `,`.

Comment: Good catch; let me correct that.

Comment: You should not type in code that you are asking a question about. Small details like this are very important in analysing your problem. Preferably, you should make a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then you will most likely get an answer within minutes.

Comment: I seem to be able to replicate your problem by using a file handle stored in an array. Perhaps this is not possible, though I could have sworn I have seen it used before. You can use `$file_handles[$index]->print("$stuff\n")` and bypass the indirect object notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to be able to replicate your problem by using a file handle stored in an array. Perhaps this is not possible, though I could have sworn I have seen it used before.

```
>perl -lwe"open $x, '>', 'a.txt' or die $!; @x = ($x); print $x[0] 'asd';"
String found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "] 'asd'"
        (Missing operator before  'asd'?)
syntax error at -e line 1, near "] 'asd'"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

The same goes for using a hash. Possible workarounds would be:

You can skip the indirect object notation and use:

```
$file_handles[$index]->print("$stuff\n")
```

Or you can use a Perl-style loop instead to print:

```
for my $fh (@file_handles) {
    print $fh "$stuff\n";
}
```

Indirect object notation is when you put the object -- in your case a file handle -- before the function call, like so:

```
my $obj = new Module;
```

Instead of traditionally:

```
my $obj = Module->new;
```

More information about indirect object notation in [perldoc perlobj](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Indirect-Object-Syntax)

Comment: Wow, I have just done what you have suggested about using indirect object notation and it did the job! However, I have no idea about what it does: can you explain it to me or point to the relevant documentation? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

With anything other than a simple scalar or a bareword for the filehandle, you have to wrap the filehandle in braces:

```
print { $file_handles[$handle_index] } "stuff to print";
```

Notice there's still no comma after the filehandle portion.

Comment: interesting: is there a logic behind this madness?

Comment: It allows the parser to know what the file handle is.